# How to join a table of stats with a table of reference (SQL or SAS)

Tags: sql, sas, backend

I have statistic data from TABLE_STATS. Ex. :

```
ID  YEARH   MONTH   STATS...
1   2023    11      40
2   2023    11      43
1   2023    12      56
2   2023    12      65
...
```

And a TABLE_REFERENCE for my ID. ex. :

```
ID PROVINCE  CITY  ...
1  QUEBEC  QUEBEC CITY
2  QUEBEC MONTREAL
...
```

And I want to simply add fields from my TABLE_REFERENCE (like REGION) to the corresponding ID of my TABLE_STATS (to build statistic by region, for example).

```
ID  YEARH   MONTH   STATS  PROVINCE
1   2023    11      40     QUEBEC
2   2023    11      43     QUEBEC
...
```

I tried multiple combinaison of "PROD SQL" codes and "DATA, MERGE" (in SAS) codes, but nothing actually does the job. Do you have the winning formula?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is a simple join on ID not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for your example.

```
data stats;
  input ID  YEARH   MONTH   STATS;
cards;
1   2023    11      40
2   2023    11      43
1   2023    12      56
2   2023    12      65
;

data reference ;
  input ID PROVINCE :$20. CITY $30. ;
cards;
1  QUEBEC  QUEBEC CITY
2  QUEBEC MONTREAL
;

proc sql;
create table want as
  select *
  from stats a
  left join reference b
  on a.id = b.id
;
quit;
```

Result

```
OBS    ID    YEARH    MONTH    STATS    PROVINCE       CITY

 1      1     2023      12       56      QUEBEC     QUEBEC CITY
 2      1     2023      11       40      QUEBEC     QUEBEC CITY
 3      2     2023      11       43      QUEBEC     MONTREAL
 4      2     2023      12       65      QUEBEC     MONTREA
```

Make sure the ID variable uniquely identifies the observations in the reference table.

Comment: That's what I tried first, but the field from my "reference" columns are empty. Don't understand, I did similar things many times before...

Comment: So none of the values match.  If  the ID variable is numeric then try rounding the values to eliminate fractional difference.  If it is character make sure to remove leading spaces or other invisible characters.